# Deleting a private GPG Key in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: gnupg, azure-cloud-shell

In Azure Cloud Shell I was able to create a GPG key.
Now I want to delete it...

```
gpg --delete-secret-key [ID-OF-KEY]
```

Which results in...

```
Delete this key from the keyring? (y/N) y
This is a secret key! - really delete? (y/N) y
gpg: deleting secret key failed: Permission denied
gpg: deleting secret subkey failed: Permission denied
```

I had permissions to create it. Why can't I delete it?

Comment: Could you please provide the process of GPG creation that you used so that we can replicate it.

Comment: I generated the key(s) with the following command: gpg --batch --gen-key pgp-params.txt